# How can I implement socket.io or the socket.io instance in different parts of the project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

good afternoon! How can I implement socket.io or the socket.io instance in different parts of the project or in different files? I have the declaration and instance of express and socket.io in the index.js file, but I want to implement socket.io methods to send data in another file where the controllers are located.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', socket=>{
   console.log('New client conected');

  // Manejo de eventos del cliente
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log('message from client:', data);
    
  });
 var data = "hi! I'm the server ";
  io.emit('message', "así que no llego nada he");
  socket.on('disconnect', () => { 
    console.log('Cliente desconectado');
  });

});

server.prependListener("request", (req, res) => {
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});

server.listen(7000, () => {
   console.log("This is the socket server running");
});
```

controller.js

```
const insertData = async(req,res)=>{
    const { 
         temperature,
         pressure, 
         altitud, 
         air_quality
         
        } = req.body;
      
    try{
        
        const connection = await getConnection();
        const result = await connection.query(`call sp_StoreMeteorologicalData('${temperature}','${pressure}','${altitud}','${air_quality}')`);
        res.status(200).json({status:"Well done!", message:"Datos registrados con exito"});


    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error.message);
    }
}
export const methods = {
    getRealTimeData,
    insertData
};
```

I've tried writing the entire socket.io instance in the controllers, but it didn't work for me. So, I would like to know if it's possible or if, when deploying to production, I need to have a specific file for the server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.